# Question on the concept of mitochondrial Eve

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics

My question is about the very definition of this common ancestor.

Why shouldn't be the mother of mitocondrial Eve the real Eva m (and so on to grand grand ...mother)? All I know on the subject comes from Wikipedia. My question comes from the idea that mitochondrial DNA is passed from mother to daughter. I do not see where to stop back in time.

Please consider that here I am not asking for details or controversies. Just the significance of mitochondrial Eve.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you call `Eva m` exactly? The MRCA of all of today's mitochondria in humans? What do you call `real Eva m`?

Comment: It is mitochondrial Eve,  not Eva and is sometimes abbreviated mt-Eve or mt-MRCA (see the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve) says:

> In human genetics, the Mitochondrial Eve (also mt-Eve, mt-MRCA) is the matrilineal most recent common ancestor (MRCA) of all currently living humans

Note the use of the words "**most recent**".  The mother and grandmother of the actual Mitochondrial Eve were living before Mitochondrial Eve, and thus are *less recent* than she is.

Comment: Thanks. I somehow skip that. I am amazed by this. How it comes that we are not from 2, 3 , n ... maternal lines ? I just discovered it yesterday and makes me wonder.